# What is Bayesian and Monte Carlo Simulation?

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo

Can someone explain in plain language for a layperson what are Bayesian and Monte Carlo simulations and the relationship between the two? I thought Bayesian was the same as Monte Carlo Simulation...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22/bayesian-and-frequentist-reasoning-in-plain-english and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165/how-would-you-explain-markov-chain-monte-carlo-mcmc-to-a-layperson . Btw, question about what are non-Bayesian MC simulations would not be a duplicate of those, but I am not sure if this is what you are asking about (if yes, please edit).

Comment: See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126904/are-all-simulation-methods-some-form-of-monte-carlo