# meaning of 'Monte Carlo' in this sentence

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning

This is from a paper 'Algorithms for Inverse Reinforcement Learning' by Ng, Russell (2001)

> We assume that we have the ability to simulate trajectories in the
>   MDP (from the initial state $s_0$) under the optimal policy, or under
>   any policy of our choice. For each policy $\pi$ that we will consider
>   (including the optimal one), we will need a way of estimating
>   $V^{\pi}(s_0)$ for any setting of the $\alpha_i$'s. To do this, we
>   first execute $m$ $\underline{\text{Monte Carlo}}$ trajectories under
>   $\pi$.

Sorry for the long quote. What is the meaning of 'Monte Carlo' in the last sentence?

My first thought would be to just run the simulation again and again $m$ times. But rethinking it, I might be very wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What Ng and Russell seem to be saying is that for each policy $\pi$ they simulate $m$ "possible" outcomes for processes starting at point $s_0$. By "trajectories" they seem to mean the possible developments in time of simulated processes -- different possible scenarios created by simulation. So you were correct, [Monte Carlo](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174133/what-are-monte-carlo-simulations/174143) stands here for "simulation" (see also [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126904/are-all-simulation-methods-some-form-of-monte-carlo/126908)).

Answer (score 0):

Monte Carlo here simply means use sampling to estimate the values. Practically this means collecting a sequence of (state, action) pairs, i.e. the trajectory using some arbitrary policy, and from this you can compute relevant quantities like `V`, etc